Come home to find+NP vs Come home to NP
He came home to find an empty bed.
Vs
He came home to an empty bed.
What is the difference between the two?

The version with "to find" suggests that he wasn't expecting it, or if he was, that the discovery had some emotional significance to him.
The version without "to find" does not have that implication, and it might even be normal, or expected.

+1. The distinction @ColinFine explains is precisely the difference between Everyvday, after a long shift at the factory, he came home to a dark, empty room and His heartache dated to the evening he came home to find an empty house; she had left him.
